# Error in C# when trying to compare a value to a string

Tags: c#

I am getting an error when trying the following in C#

```
if (state != 'WI' && state != 'IL')
```

That statement is giving me an error that states: Error operator != cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' or 'char'

If this is not possible what is a way to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use double quotes for strings:

```
if (state != "WI" && state != "IL")
```

Single quotes are useful for single characters:

```
char c = 'A';
if (c != 'B') ...
```

EDIT: others have suggested using `Equals` to compare and I don't fully agree that it should replace an `==` approach unless you have a reason to use it. Firstly, if  `state` is `null` then an exception will be thrown from writing `state.Equals("WI")`. A way around this is to use `String.Compare(state, "WI")` instead but that no longer returns a `bool` and will need to be checked against an integer (0 is returned if they are the same):

```
if (String.Compare(state, "WI") != 0)
```

Secondly, I would suggest using either `Equals` or `String.Compare` if case-sensitivity matters since both provide overloads to handle that issue:

```
string foo = "Foo";
string otherFoo = "foo";
Console.WriteLine("Equals: {0}", foo.Equals(otherFoo));
Console.WriteLine("Equals case insensitive: {0}", foo.Equals(otherFoo, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
Console.WriteLine("Compare: {0}", String.Compare(foo, otherFoo) == 0);
Console.WriteLine("Compare case insensitive: {0}", String.Compare(foo, otherFoo, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0);

// make foo null
foo = null;
Console.WriteLine("Null Compare: {0}", String.Compare(foo, otherFoo) == 0);
Console.WriteLine("Null Equals: {0}", foo.Equals(otherFoo)); // exception
```

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes to enclose string literals!

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes to delimit your strings. These mean `char`.

Try:

```
if (state != "WI" && state != "IL")
```

with double quotes.

While the code you have is perfectly OK, you should consider using the `string.Equals` method:

```
if (!state.Equals("WI") && !state.Equals("IL"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "WI" also use equals method of string as `!state.Equals("WI")`

Comment: Why should he use Equals? It causes problems if state==null and gains nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !state.Equals("WI") && !state.Equals("IL") ) {
}
```

Comment: That's going to throw an exception if `state == null`

Answer (score 0):

> If this is not possible what is a way to accomplish my goal.

RTFEM!<sup>*</sup> The error message is clearly indicating that one of the operands is being interpreted as a `char` and not a `string`. In the case of

```
state != 'WI'
```

there are two operands: `state` and `'WI'`. If you've declared `state` as a `string`, then clearly it can't be `state` that is being interpreted as a `char`. Thus, it must be `'WI'` that is being interpreted as a `char`. And now you ask yourself, "Why is this being interpreted as a `char`? How do I declare a `string` in C# if not enclosing in single-quotes ("`'`")?" So then you Google ["declare string C#"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=declare+string+C%23) and click "I'm Feeling Lucky" and you hit [Strings (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx) which tells you to declare a `string` literal you enclose in double-quotes ("`"`").

Thus,

```
if (state != "WI" && state != "IL")
```

<sup>*</sup> This is not meant to be rude so don't take it that way. This answer is very much in the philosophy of "If you teach a man to fish...."